# javascript strategy / best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting into writing some more complex javascript applications, and I'm running into the limitations of my own knowledge-- please forgive any naming errors or obvious noob stuff, I'm not a js pro!

I have about 4 or 5 scripts I've put in their own files, just to keep things a little easier to maintain. So maybe there's one script that deals with building page elements (like complex forms), another that just handles data, creating generic ajax request objects, defining parsers and error functions for the data returned, and another that is purely display-oriented.

I've set global variables in the page that then get populated by various scripts that get loaded at run time. For example, I define `var myapp = { };` in the main HTML page, and then in the scripts various function populate this "namespace" like:

```
myapp.myfunction = function(){
    // do stuff
}
```

The problem is that despite all the scripts including a `$(document).ready(function()` block that wraps all function definitions, when a function is called from one script that refers to another (that is, if my `data.js` file calls a function `myapp.myDisplayFunction` that is in the `display.js` file, I sometimes get an `Object has no method 'myDisplayFunction'`

Other than slamming all functions into one massive script, how do you deal with this problem? Is there a best practice that I'm missing? or is this just a question of specifying a different order that the scripts are called in?

Thanks

Comment: Just make sure that if one script depends on another, the "another" is included before the "one script".

Comment: I don't see why a function could not be defined if you don't call any of them before the document is ready. And if you're just defining functions, what's the point in wrapping your definitions in $(document).ready(function() ?

Comment: Check out the module pattern.  Here is [one decent link](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth), but I'm sure there are many out there.

Comment: @julio, Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520906/approaches-to-modular-client-side-javascript-without-namespace-pollution/13520940#13520940

Comment: Function declarations/expressions do not need to be enclosed in `$(document).ready()`, only the execution of those functions. Go ahead and define them outside, but fire any initialization code from inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Are you loading your modules asynchronously or why does the method not exist? Please provide some demo code that replicates the issue

Comment: Function definitions should never go in `$(document).ready` - that is where your initialization code goes.

Answer (score 0):

When you are not sure if method you are about to call exists (is already loaded) you can do a check:

```
if (myapp) //my app namespace is defined
{
    if (myapp.myFunction) //myFunction is defined
    {
        myapp.myFunction();
    }
    else
        alert('You have to load myFile.js first!');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the function before using:

```
if(typeof(myapp.myDisplayFunction) !== undefined) {
    // do your stuff
} else {
    // wait for a while
}
```

And check whether you have `async` attribute set while loading the `.js` files.